# Regarding if else statements in C language

Tags: c, if-statement

Please explain to me why this code is wrong for the task and below I have explained all the four conditions -[][1]

```
#include stdio.h
int main()    
{
      int n;
      scanf ("%d", &n);     //taking input
      if (n / 2 != 0)
        {
          printf ("Weird");     //checking first condition
        }
      else if (n % 2 == 0 && 2 <= n <= 5)
        {               //checking second condition
          printf ("Not Weird");
        }
      else if (n % 2 == 0 && 6 <= n <= 20)
        {               //checking third condition
          printf ("Weird");
        }
      else if (n % 2 == 0 && n > 20)
        {               //checking fourth condition
          printf ("Not Weird");
        }
      else
        {
          printf ("Error");
        }
      return 0;
    }
```

this is the image for the question[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtY7o.png**

Comment: Explain why you think your program is not working correctly.

Comment: `2 <= n <= 5` is not valid syntax in C. You probably want `2 <= n && n <= 5`.

Comment: The first condition `if (n / 2 != 0)` will be true unless `n` is equal to -1, 0 or 1. So why are you then checking for values of `n` up to and beyond 20? Perhaps you could explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @goodvibration it is almost certainly not what they want, but it is still _syntactically_ valid.

Answer (score 1):

### Testing for Odd or Even

`n / 2 != 0` does not test whether `n` is odd. `n/2` calculates the quotient that results from dividing `n` by 2 (rounding any fraction down). So `0/2` is 0, `1/2` is 0, `2/2` is 1, `3/2` is 1, `4/2` is 2, and so on. So `n / 2 != 0` is true for all `n` other than −1, 0, and 1.

To test whether a number is odd, you can use `n % 2 != 0`. `n%2` calculates the remainder from the division. If it is zero, `n` is even. If `n` is not zero, `n` is odd.

### Using Else Efficiently

Once you have tested whether `n` is odd using `n % 2 != 0`, you do not have to test whether it is even in the `else` clauses. The `else` expressions and their statements will be evaluated only if the `if` expression is false, which happens (after the correction above) only when `n` is even. So we do not need to test again.

### Testing For an Interval

In C, `2 <= n <= 5` does not test whether `n` is between 2 and 5. It is parsed as `(2 <= n) <= 5`. This is evaluated by comparing `2` to `n`, which produces 0 (if false) or 1 (if true). This result, 0 or 1, is then used in `… <= 5`. Since 0 and 1 are both less than or equal to 5, the result is always 1 (for true).

To test whether `n` is greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to 5, you must write this out explicitly: `2 <= n` and `n <= 5`, which we join with the “and” operator, `&&`: `2 <= n && n <= 5`.

### Other Issues

The proper form for including `stdio.h` is `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include stdio.h`.

A proper declaration for `main` is `int main(void)`, not `int main()`.

### Corrected Program

A program with these issues corrected is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);     //taking input
    if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf ("Weird");     //checking first condition
    }
    else if (2 <= n && n <= 5)
    {               //checking second condition
        printf ("Not Weird");
    }
    else if (6 <= n && n <= 20)
    {               //checking third condition
        printf ("Weird");
    }
    else if (n > 20)
    {               //checking fourth condition
        printf ("Not Weird");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the line:

```
if (n / 2 != 0)
```

The compiler will not complain, but you will get unexpected results at run time.

Here you meant to check if the remainder of division by 2 is not equal to zero (i.e.: modulus operator), and not the division by 2. This line should be

```
if (n % 2 != 0)
```

Second thing: you can't tell C to compare values in ranges like this `2 >= n >= 4`. You will have to split the comparison into 2 comparisons. This line:

```
else if (n % 2 == 0 && 2 <= n <= 5)
```

Should be:

```
else if (n % 2 == 0 && 2 <= n && n <= 5)
```

You will need to fix all the lines that have this comparison as well.

Comment: `The compiler will not complain, but you will get unexpected results at run time.` the result is 100% expected.

Comment: @P__J__: Not by the OP. When somebody writes something is “unexpected,” they do not necessarily mean “This is not expected given the requirements of the C standard.” They may just mean the author of a program will not get the results they expect, because their expectation is based on a mistake or misunderstanding. If you voted down for that reason, you should rethink your vote.

Comment: @P__J__ the OP meant to check if a given number is odd or not. If n==3 then dividing by 2 will not equal to zero which satisfies the first check, so will n==4 or any non-zero value. That is unexpected

Comment: @EricPostpischil 10k user has to be IMO more precise. ***Noblesse oblige***

Comment: @Ahmad sorry but I cant understand your comment. 3 and 4 are not special number here. Another one is. In my answer you can see what this statement does.

Comment: @P__J__ did you read the problem requirement in the image linked in the question? The OP is asked to check if the given number is odd

Comment: *`You will need to fix all the lines that have this typo as well.`* it is not the typo.  typo is `voletile`, `unsiggned` etc etc

Comment: I asked you about your commenrt. I simple do not understand it